# How to split the sentence from user input (sscanf,fgets)

Tags: c, if-statement, input, scanf, fgets

So i am trying to split the input user and assign them to specific variables. First input written from user will be Capital Character , then whitespace and second word.

**Did i used fgets,sscanf correctly to split the sentence ?**

For instance, if i write:  "A red" , everything should work.

If i write "a red" , it should not work, because a is not capital

If i write "A" , it should print that second word is not given. But it prints that second word is given :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CAPACITY 255

int main(void) {
  char name[MAX_CAPACITY];
  char input[MAX_CAPACITY]; // for sscanf
  char color[MAX_CAPACITY];  // this will be the second word from the sentence
  char letter;

  printf("Enter your name: ");
  fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
  sscanf(name, "%[^\n]", name);  // to get rid of \n

  while(1){
      printf("Dear %s, enter a capital letter and a color : ",name);
      fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
      sscanf(input, "%c %s",&letter,color);
      
      // if letter is not capital, then stop the programm
      if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'){
        printf("Dear %s, I wish you farewell and hope to see you again soon !!!\n",name);
        break;
      }
      
      // if second word is empty, then print error message
      if(color[0] == '\0'){
        printf("Second word is not given!\n");
      }else{
        printf("Thank you, the second word is given\n");
        break;
      }
      color[0] = '\0'; // if i don't write this, program doesn't work properly, idk why
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color` is not initialized, so you must not rely on the value of `color[0]` when `sscanf()` failed to read things to that.

You should check the return value of `sscanf()` (and `fgets()`) to check if they read all of expected things.

Also note that you should use the standard function [`islower()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/islower) instead of `letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'` if it is not banned.